# How can I change my Trello avatar?

Tags: trello

When I registered with Trello (using my Google account), it seemed like Trello used my email's Gravatar picture as the account avatar.

Is it possible, and if so how, to use the profile picture of my Google account?

Can I change my avatar to something other than the one from gravatar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't (currently) get the avatar from your google profile.  Trello only uses google for signin; it doesn't request access to any of your personal information (e.g. your google profile)

Trello defaults to using your [gravatar](http://gravatar.com) (if you have one), however you can also upload your own avatar using the following steps:

1. Go to your [**account page**](https://trello.com/my/account) (By clicking your avatar in the upper right corner and clicking "Account", or by going directly to https://trello.com/my/account)
2. Go to the "**Avatar**" section
3. Here you have three options:

   - Use a [gravatar](http://gravatar.com) (if you have one)
   - Upload your own avatar
   - Use your initials as an "avatar"

(I've included these instructions since "[How do I set or change my avatar](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19921/how-do-i-set-or-change-my-avatar-in-trello)" is considered a duplicate of this question)

Comment: Is it possible to use the StackExchange gravatar ? If yes, then how?

Comment: @Itamar: Do you mean the random pattern that stack exchange uses if you don't have a gravatar?

Comment: I think the idea is that if you use the same email address for both your StackExchange and Trello accounts, and you've already set up a Gravatar on that email for Stack Exchange, then it will just appear in Trello automatically.

Comment: Yes @DanielLeCheminant, I meant the random pattern that is currently on my profile - I assumed it was from gravatar but I may be wrong

Comment: @clare, I use the same email address for both but there's only a big `I` on my Trello profile.

Comment: The random pattern is from gravatar, but we've configured it not to use the pattern and to use your initials instead.  We felt that the initials were more useful if you're dealing with people that you know (but who haven't configured gravatar)

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to change your profile picture at gravatar.com:

Unfortunately, if you haven't ever done it before, it can be a tricky process.

1. Go to gravatar.com and click "Get your Gravatar today" (which should take you to gravatar.com/site/signup/)
2. Enter your email address (the same one that you're using with Trello)
3. Click on the link sent to that email address by gravatar
4. Fill out a username/password with gravatar
5. It'll say "Whoops, looks like you don't have any images yet!".  Click on "Add one by clicking here"
6. Click "My computer's hard drive"
7. Click "Choose file", and locate the file you want to use for your avatar
8. Click "Next"
9. Crop the avatar if necessary, then click "Crop and Finish!"
10. Click "Rated G" (unless, for some reason, it isn't suitable for all audiences)
11. You're done.  It may take an hour or so for the new gravatar to show up on trello.com

Only 11 easy steps and an hour or more to wait!

Obviously we'd like this to be easier/automatic.