# How do I set or change my avatar in Trello?

Tags: trello, avatar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I use the profile picture from my Google account as my Trello avatar?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19084/can-i-use-the-profile-picture-from-my-google-account-as-my-trello-avatar)

I can't find where the option is to set or change my avatar. Is this even possible?

Comment: See [this](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19084/can-i-use-the-profile-picture-from-my-google-account-as-my-trello-avatar)  question.